# influxdb proxy or influxdb fetches data from other influxdb

Tags: proxy, influxdb

Is it possible to setup influxdb to fetch data from other influxdb?
or have some local log proxy for influx data.

e.g. I have 10 backend server. I wish every backend servers middleware code to log events locally in influxdb or some local log proxy.

I wish to setup another server with influxdb that will fetch logs from every backend server and accumulate it.

I can't find if such configuration is possible. May be I miss some "search term" to google for it.

Comment: You can do this if you like. Why you would is beyond me though. You would have to write your own cronjob/script for this. Influx db does not support data replication/duplication in the free version.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/) from InfluxData - it is an agent for Collecting & Reporting Metrics & Data.

You can install a Telegraf instance on each of your 10 middleware servers and [report data to local Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/http_listener) instead of InfluxDB.

In Telegraf you can either configure [output to your InfluxDB](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/influxdb) or even [point it](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/kafka) to some persistent stream like [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) and configure another Telegraf which will [read data from Kafka](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/kafka_consumer) and persist it to InfluxDB